# Why is my Yongnuo YN-568EX flash stuck in ETTL mode?

Tags: flash, troubleshooting, yongnuo, ttl

[image: Shot of the YN-568EX back LCD]

I’ve just bought this flash. At first it seems fine, and I can switching the mode from ETTL to M and Multi mode. But then after a while, I can’t change to other modes and the flash is stuck in ETTL. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: The amount of wear on the labelling would indicate this has been rather well-used in the past. Have you considered this might be the very reason someone sold it, it was beginning to fail?